# When using hibernate criteria with alias, the resultSet is a list of tuples of objects

Tags: hibernate, alias, criteria

I have a parent/child relationship in my application.  Both parent and child have a name field, and I want to be able to select all children where the child.name is like some string, OR the parent.name is like some string.  This is the criteria that I have so far:

```
Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Child.class, "c")
        .createAlias("parent", "p")
        .add(Restrictions.or(
                Restrictions.ilike("c.name", searchTerm, MatchMode.ANYWHERE),
                Restrictions.ilike("p.name", searchTerm, MatchMode.ANYWHERE)));
```

This is giving me the number of results I expect, and the results are nearly what I want, except that each item in the result set is a tuple of the Parent and the Child object (a List where each item is another List, with a size of 2, where the first item is the parent, and the second item is the child).  I don't want the tuple, especially since there is already a reference to the parent from within the child already.

I have analyzed the generated SQL query, and ran the resulting SQL query against my database by hand, and everything else appears to be as expected.

Can anyone tell me why my Criteria query above is giving me tupled results?

Thanks in advance.
Tonya

Answer (score 0):

I spent many hours perusing the Internet and trying many different possible solutions, and I was unable to find anything that worked.  Anytime I used the "createAlias", hibernate returned a list of lists instead of just a list of the objects I was interested in.  I finally had to resort to rewriting my DAO method to use HQL instead of Criteria.

```
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Child c where child.name like :searchTerm or child.parent.name like :searchTerm");
query.setParameter("searchTerm", '%' + searchTerm + '%');
```

I find the HQL solution to be effective, but the code is messier to my eye, having to manually compensate for "like" clauses, and using enum values in the query, etc.

I do not like this solution as much, and if anyone can help figure out how to achieve the above with Criteria, I would still like to know this solution.

Thanks,
Tonya

Comment: I have also found that adding the following to my Criteria solved the problem:

    .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);